# How to show a fragment when soft keyboard is on the screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

As you know when the soft keyboard is on the screen you can see a part of the main layout.How can I fill this part with a fragment? This fragment appears when the soft keyboard is on and it will gone with the soft keyboard.The main problem is how to evaluate the size and location of the fragment in different size and resolution.

I want to put an ImageIcon, a big EditText that shows what you have typed and a confirm button. Absolutely my problem is only to manage this fragment not the content of it.

Comment: Since there's no notification when the soft keyboard is shown, there's no way to do this.  I'm not sure why you'd want it anyway-  if the user tapped in an edit text to bring up the soft keyboard, then they can already see what they're typing in the existing edit field.

Comment: Maybe there is no difference between these to situation for you, but it's a matter of UI.There can be some tips and good points for users in the new fragment.